# is it possible enable or disable showPerformanceOverlay dynamic in flutter

Tags: flutter

Now I am using `showPerformanceOverlay` to show performance information in flutter. But when runs in real device, I want to close performance UI without reinstall the flutter app. Is it possible to enable or disable the `showPerformanceOverlay` | `checkerboardOffscreenLayers`  | `checkerboardRasterCacheImages` in real device? This is the configuration I am using in the app:

```
return MaterialApp(
        title: 'Cruise',
        theme: currentTheme,
        checkerboardOffscreenLayers: true,
        checkerboardRasterCacheImages: true,
        showPerformanceOverlay: true,
        localizationsDelegates: [
          // ... app-specific localization delegate[s] here
          // TODO: uncomment the line below after codegen
          // AppLocalizations.delegate,
          GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate,
          GlobalWidgetsLocalizations.delegate,
          GlobalCupertinoLocalizations.delegate,
          AppLocalizations.delegate
        ],
        supportedLocales: [
          const Locale('en', ''), // English, no country code
          const Locale('ar', ''), // Arabic, no country code
          const Locale.fromSubtags(languageCode: 'zh'), // Chinese *See Advanced Locales below*
          // ... other locales the app supports
        ],
        //home: HomeNew(),
        home: routes.buildPage('home', null),
        onGenerateRoute: (RouteSettings settings) {
          return MaterialPageRoute<Object>(builder: (BuildContext context) {
            return routes.buildPage(settings.name, settings.arguments);
          });
        });
```

Comment: trued to rebuild `MaterialApp` with  `showPerformanceOverlay: false` ?

Comment: I do not want to rebuild the app and reinstall app @pskink

Comment: this is the only way to change `showPerformanceOverlay` - what is wrong with rebuilding `MaterialApp` widget?

Comment: how to change it in real device the easy way without reinstall app? @pskink

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use stateful widget. Example for toggling debug mode banner:

```
class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  
  bool showDebugBanner = false;
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: showDebugBanner,
      home: Scaffold(
        floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
          child: Icon(Icons.remove_red_eye),
          onPressed: () => setState(() => showDebugBanner = !showDebugBanner),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```